# How to get meta data from WooCommerce product attribute terms

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

The meta_value of a particular attribute list holds the name of an image.  Is there a way I can access the list of meta_values for an attribute?
This gives me all the names but I need the meta_values as well:

```
global $product; 
$stain=$product->get_attribute('pa_stain-color');
echo $stain;
```

How can I get the meta_values?  I've tried a number of variants on this but simply cannot get the meta_values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As each product attribute is a custom WooCommerce product **taxonomy**, for a specific custom taxonomy you can get the terms attached to a product and then the term meta data as follows:

```
$taxonomy = 'pa_stain-color';

$terms    = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), $taxonomy ); // Get terms for the product

if ( ! empty($terms) ) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $meta_data = get_term_meta( $term->term_id ); // Get all meta data

        // Display the term name
        echo '<p>' . $term->name . '</p>'; 

        // Raw array output from term meta data
        echo '<pre>' . print_r($meta_data, true) . '</pre>'; 
    }
}
```

Documentation: [WordPress `get_term_meta()` function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_term_meta/)

Comment: That was perfect!  Exactly what I was looking for.  Thank you!